# Am I able to use AWS EventBridge (or alternative) in order to re-run a lambda after an hour if the past one fails?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have written a lambda using Python which is dependent upon external APIs which can occasionally go down. This is triggered once a day using EventBridge to gather data from yesterday, and updates a file in S3 at the same time every day.

I was wondering how I would be able to re-run the Lambda, which includes a check as to whether the external API is functioning at the start, every 1-2 hours for the rest of the day until it successfully works? It would need to stop at 11pm so as to not go into the next calendar day.

Specifically I am using the Google Search Console API which should have updated every 4 hours but hasn't in this case for 30.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [CloudWatch event schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) can trigger your lambda periodically throughout the day.  Using a `cron` expression, you can have your lambda invoked at suitable intervals.

The lambda first looks up the `last_modified` property on the target S3 file.  If `last_modified` is not today, proceed and call the API.  If `last_modified` is today, we have nothing to do, so the lambda returns without doing anything.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense! I was looking to avoid that (in my head) thinking it would be too costly to check, but just popped into a cost calculator and didn't realise just how ridiculously cheap they can be. Appreciate it.